# LazyInitialization Exception while accessing id of a lazy loaded field

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am using Hibernate in my java project. I am having following entity structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "engine_id", nullable = false)
    private Engine engine;
}
```

Now when I load `Car` entity from db, obviously `Engine` entity won't be loaded as it is lazy loaded field, but the id (primary key) for the `Engine` will be loaded.

Now if I do car.getEngine().getId(), then it is throwing LazyInitialization Exception. As Id part is already loaded, then why getId() is throwing exception?

Comment: Please post the exception if you get one... Also, probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250414/hibernate-getid-is-loading-the-object-even-though-it-is-lazy explains your problem (if you have your fields annotated in your Engine class too)

Answer (score 0):

> when I load `Car` entity from db

Are you absolutely sure this object is fully loaded?

If it's lazy loaded, `Engine` id as well as other attributes aren't loaded yet hence the exception. I would suggest you to play with `Hibernate.initialize(obj)` at every level to see where exactly the failure is.